# I have this json response.... i want to add it to my android spinner? How i add this

Tags: android, arraylist

```
{"state":[{"state_id":"101","state_name":"Haryana"},{"state_id":"102","state_name":"Punjab"}]}
```

this is my json response.... i want to add it to my spinner in android.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just create array of state_name value and pass that array to adapter and set adapter to spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list and add all the values you need to show in your spinner

```
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> listID = new ArrayList<String>();
     list.add("state name");
     list.add("state id");
     ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

> Create an adapter and set the adapter to your spinner.

```
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

> now get the spinner selected item position

```
int position= spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

with this position value you can get state code in the arraylist

Comment: its working brother......but i need a modification. I want to show the state_name but when i select an item then it must return the value of state_id.

Comment: Simpler way to do this is have two arraylist one with statename values and other with state id values.Finally use spinner index position to get state name and state id